# L'étymologie de « tirelire » : explications ?

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison

J'ai spontanément pensé que l'étymologie de la *tirelire* (voir aussi [*cochon tirelire*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochon_tirelire)), ce « petit récipient de forme variée portant une fente à sa partie supérieure où l'on peut introduire de la monnaie pour constituer des économies » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirelire)) avait trait à la *lire* italienne (l'ancienne unité monétaire). Or il n'en est rien et on nous indique que c'est attesté vers 1223 et que c'est :

> [...] probablement le même mot que dans le refrain de chanson
>   tire-lire en usage au moyen-âge (XIIIe s.) et de formation
>   onomatopéique : à la même époque, on rencontre [tirelirer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirelirer), « faire
>   entendre ce son, cette chanson », appliqué spécialement au chant de
>   l'alouette (v. 1550). Tirelire a pu désigner par plaisanterie un pot
>   percé d'une fente où l'on gardait des pièces de monnaies, sans doute à
>   cause du bruit qu'elles faisaient en y tombant. [...]
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, chez
>   *Robert* ]

À l'étymologie de [*tirelirer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirelirer) on réfère à ceci au TLFi :

> L'autrier chivachoie
>   leis un boix ki verdoie
>   trovai pastoure aigniaus gardant,
>   et jolivement chantant
>   'teirelire un don,
>   Robeson,
>   musairs viennent et musairs vont,
>   teirelire un don tridon.'
>
> [ [*Romances et Pastourelles*](https://archive.org/details/romancesetpasto00bartgoog/page/n189), II, 46, 5 et 8 ]

À [*tirelire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirelire) on réfère à [*Les Miracles de Nostre-Dame*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BANTAAAAcAAJ&dq=Les%20Miracles%20de%20Nostre%20Dame%20tirelire&pg=RA1-PA685#v=onepage&q=Les%20Miracles%20de%20Nostre%20Dame%20tirelire&f=false) (voir aussi le [manuscrit](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b6000451c/f442.image), col. 1, 15e vers à partir du bas) de [Gautier de Coinci](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautier_de_Coinci) où l'on a « Ainz briserai ma tirelire » (ds. la version de Koenig).

---

- Y a-t-il un lien entre le bruit des pièces qui tombent, la chanson du
  moyen-âge, l'alouette et Les Miracles de Notre-Dame ??
- Autrement comment explique-t-on le lien entre le bruit des pièces qui
  tombent dans la tirelire et le mot ; où est la plaisanterie ?

Comment: sur wikitionnaire on parle bien du bruit des pièces mais aussi de tirare lire le fait de jeter de la monaie, de la lirette libre https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirelire

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda Merci ! Cependant d'où tirent-ils ça ? Ils ne présentent aucune source sauf Ac.8 qui ne contient pas cette information. Cette information n'apparaît pas au DHLF, qui fait état d'une suggestion de P. Guiraud où il rapprochait ça à _turlure_ mais indique que cette explication _ne s'impose pas_. Je ne sais pas. Si vous étayez l'affirmation du Wiktionnaire, n'hésitez pas à répondre !

Comment: Ce manuscrit est d'une facture impayable.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Sauf pour ceux qui on les moyens de la payer... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

En supplément de tout ce qui a été dit, je viens apporter mon **idée**.

C'est probablement tiré par les cheveux, mais on pourrait imaginer qu'une note de la [Lyre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyre) ressemblerait au son produit par une pièce qui tombe dans un récipient.

On aurait donc associé **tire** (tirer une corde puis la relâcher, pour produire un son sur un instrument à cordes) et **Lyre** (l'instrument en lui-même), et l'association des deux mots aurait donné tirelire.

J'ai mis l'emphase sur **idée** puisque je ne suis ni un étymologiste, ni un expert en histoire.

Comment: Oui, c'est tyré par les cheveux...

Comment: @jlliagre … alors les chauves, à force de s'arracher les cheveux pour trouver des rimes sont-ils poètes ? La musique des mots tintinnabule-t-elle dans les escarcelles (peu probable) ou dans les pots de fer ? Rêver à la sonorité des mots est pure humanité depuis que la parole reflète les sensations de la vie, ou, un crime contre le savoir, un pied de nez  aux académismes qui enferment le souffle articulé dans une protection qui rime avec prison ? … Toute personne odysséene  plussoie allégrement, la vie est ainsi faite …

Comment: @Personne Ce n'était (au départ) qu'une joke, un jeu de mots... J'aurais dû mettre un smiley ! Loin de moi de condamner l'idée, d'autant plus qu'en lisant de plus près le TLFi, on découvre que l'idée n'est justement pas absurde puisqu'on y évoque l'hypothèse d'une influence de *lirelire* qui est la réduplication de *lyre*.

Comment: Capillo-lyré ! ;-)

Comment: Je n'ai rien mal pris au contraire, j'ai beaucoup ri des deux jeux de mots ! J'ai même appris des mots de la belle tirade de @Personne, merci pour ça !