# Quelle est l'onomatopée des pièces de monnaies tombant dans un pot percé d'une fente ?

Tags: onomatopées, son

Quelle [ononmatopée(s)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Onomatop%C3%A9es_en_fran%C3%A7ais) représenterai(en)t le son que font des pièces de monnaies tombant dans un pot percé d'une fente ou dans une tirelire ?

Comment: J'aurais dis "tching" pour une onomatopée mais je ne le trouve pas ailleurs. Sinon tintement serait naturel mais pas une vraie onomatopée.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Il est [ici](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ching#Etymology_2). Ça me fait penser que je dis _whoops_ ou similairement et non pas _oups_. Je suis francophone mais il semble que pour certaines onomatopées l'anglais soit ma référence...

Comment: Je vis depuis 12 ans au Royaume-Uni et mes onomatopées sont donc contaminées aussi. Cependant, de mon point de vue, les onomatopées sont une partie très plastique du langage et propices aux innovations et emprunts !

Answer (score 1):

Il y le [**tintin**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tin-tin) du verbe tinter comme une cloche (CNRTL)

> (avec le bruit métallique d'une pièce de monnaie). Argent, sous,
> espèces (sonnantes). J'entends souvent tintin pour argent: des
> tintins; un mec aux tintins (J. Demeure, au 8eGénie, 1918-1919 ds
> Esnault, Notes compl. Poilu, [1919], 1956).

[**Ding**](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/40267)

> Onomatopée de la cloche, de la sonette, du tintement, de la machine à sous, de l'horloge ; onomatopée de la cloche de l'omnibus ; onomatopée de la pièce de monnaie tombant sur le sol

Et le [**cliquetis**](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=200575095;) (TLFi)

> CLIQUETIS, subst. masc. A. Succession de bruits métalliques, secs,
> brefs, légers et aigus, produits par certains objets sonores de
> dimension réduite, principalement en métal, remués, secoués ou
> heurtés.

Sans oublier : [L'étymologie de « tirelire » : explications ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33314/l%c3%a9tymologie-de-tirelire-explications)

Comment: Merci ! Un commentaire sur le bruit quand la tirelire contient déjà plusieurs pièces vs. vide ? Je peux entendre _ding_ quand elle est vide, même parfois il y a un roulement avant que la pièce ne s'immobilise, dépendamment de la forme de la tirelire...

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse — https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tintinnabuler B-REM 2 — Utilisé habituellement pour les bouteilles, les verres qui s'entrechoquent.

Comment: @Personne Oui d'accord, mais je cherche l'onomatopée comme telle et non un verbe qui y réfère ou en provient. Vous entendez _ding, tine, ting, tchih_ quand la pièce atterrit dans la pile ? Disons d'abord on enligne la pièce dans la fente, il y a parfois un son plus représentatif de la matière de la tirelire, puis la pièce frotte parfois sur la fente et on entend un truc, et enfin elle atterrit dans la pile et on entend comme une percussion de maracas en sourdine.

Comment: *klinggg'-klikling',* ou *klinggg'-kliklikling'*, avec le *k* pour le choc (et légère prolongation de l'onomatopée qui sera assourdie ensuite) et la répétition de *kli* pour la réponse des autres pièces. Normalement on approche la pièce délicatement, s'il y a choc : *tak* et glissement sur un matériau dur : *schwiiiip'*, peuvent être envisagés.

Comment: Le *tintin* n'est plus audible depuis que La créature graphique d'Hergé est devenu mondialement connue, autant que Milou :-) — Cliquetis convient tout à fait comme définition, pas comme onomatopée.